# What's wrong with my mail function

Tags: php, email

This code is supposed to send an email to my hotmail address:

```
<?php
$subject = 'test';
$from = 'test@test.com';
$reply_to = 'test@test.com';
$message = 'test';
$headers = "From: ".$from. "\r\n" . "Reply-To: ".$reply_to. "\r\n" . "X-Mailer: PHP/" . phpversion();
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\r\n";
mail('my_hotmail_address@hotmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers); 
?>
```

Yet on my two hosting providers it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Always do some debugging-fu. Try `var_dump(mail('my_hotmail_address@hotmail.com', $subject, $message, $headers)); ` and see what's the output !

Comment: Does `if (mail(...)) { echo 'it worked'; }` return? It can be either spam filtered or it's failing to send.

Comment: Spam folder is empty. Did a var_dump, returns: bool(true).

Comment: Aren't you missing `"\r\n"` after `phpversion()`?

Answer (score 4):

Try sending it to another email address (gmail or something). You wouldn't say, but hotmail is really critical when it comes to recieving emails. If the domain don't match the senders IP, it's easily blocked by hotmail. Gmail is not that critical and does other google things to make it work.

Here is a header that works for me for sending to hotmail:

```
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "From: ". $Name . " <" . $email . ">\r\n";
```

Make sure either your MX records IP is the same as your server IP (if your server handles your email) or put a SPF file in your DNS. This grants your server through DNS to send. Hotmail checks that.

Good luck

Comment: I agree on that. Also try to use some real email in from.